# CoreData memory and performance managment

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, memory-management, database-performance

I'm building an iPhone App where the user gets to add data to a CoreData database and generate reports of them later on. 
the report generation will be repeated and will have to be displayed frequently.

My question is:
should I copy the CoreData entities (might be in hundreds) to an array and process them or should I use nested fetch request to retrieve the data. I'm worried about either the app being too slow or too memory consuming.

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question. No, you don't need to "copy" Core Data entities.

Comment: What does "nested fetch request" mean?

Comment: thank you for your reply Mundi, I'm not sure what do you mean by specific? I come from an electronic background and not sure how the IOS would manage the memory and performance.

I meant a fetch request that has more than one condition.

Comment: @nasser - If you don't know how it will behave, then you should write the code, and then test it.  Apple provides a number of mechanisms to do performance tests, and several instruments specifically designed to measure application performance.

Comment: When you fetch from Core Data results are returned in arrays so "copying" to arrays is unnecessary. Once the data is in memory access is fairly rapid. Data fetches perform well, particularly if you limit the number of attributes you retrieve and perform the fetch on a different thread. You will want to watch out for memory utilization if your reports use a lot of data - another argument for not copying data to arrays.